# Probability of forming a triangle - solution seems to be wrong?

Tags: probability

The question is what is the probability of forming a triangle from 2 random cuts of a stick?

There are many ways to solve this problem, and I'm trying to figure out if I'm misunderstanding something, or if the solution presented in my book is wrong:

[image]

So the book first assumes that $x < y$, so the 3 segment lengths are $x, y-x, 1-y$, and the constraints are
$$
y > 0.5 \\
y < 0.5 + x \\
x < 0.5 
$$

The book then states that this corresponds to the top left triangle. This seems to violate the constraint $y < 0.5 + x$? Shouldn't it be the triangle with vertices (0, 0.5) (0.5, 1) (0.5, 0.5)?

Similarly, if we now consider $x > y$, we have the following constraints:
$$
x > \frac{1}{2} \\
y > x - 0.5\\
y < 0.5 \\
$$
The book states that this corresponds to the top right triangle, but I think this is wrong too. Shouldn't this correspond to the triangle with vertices (0.5, 0), (0.5, 0.5), and (1, 0.5)?

Am I misunderstanding something, or is the book shaded regions wrong?

Comment: the shaded regions in book are wrong, you are right!

Comment: That book has tonnes of errors. Stay vigilant!

Comment: @RagibZaman I've noticed some, and I think a lot of the solutions are poorly written too :(. I don't actually have the books, just a question bank with solutions from a collection of books.

Comment: @user5965026 Is that bank of questions specific to quantitative interviews? If so, could you point me to where I could find it?

Comment: Yeah, my friend sent it to me, and he said it's the questions from A Quantitative Guide to Finance Interviews, Heard on the Street Chapter 4, and 50 Hard Problems in Probability, and also from 
Vault Guide to Advanced Finance & Quantitative Interviews . Are you interviewing for quant positions soon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this from "50 hard problems in probability" (or something like that) by Mosteller?

Anyhow, your analysis looks correct to me: the point (x= 0, y = 1) is in the left grey triangle, but clearly does not correspond to a triangle being formable from the three broken pieces of the stick.

The left grey triangle should go from the center of the square out to the diagonal that's to the NW of that center.

My guess is that this was an artist's mistake in drawing the figure, but who knows?

Regardless, that book is a treasure!

Comment: Yup. Wait, are you sure that "The left grey triangle should go from the center of the square out to the diagonal that's to the NW of that center?" That would mean (x=0,y=1) is valid. Based on the constraints, I think the vertices of the triangle should be (0.5, 0.5) (0, 0.5) (0.5, 1)?

Comment: Sorry...i wasnt' all that clear. The current left grey triangle has two orthogonal edges and a diagonal edge; let's call that diagonal edge $E$. Then I meant that the triangle *should* be flipped across the edge $E$, i.e., it should go from the center of the square (i.e., (0.5, 0.5)) out to $E$. In other words: exactly the triangle you described.

Comment: The book is "A Practical Guide to Quantitative Finance Interviews" by Xinfeng Zhou, and it's riddled with errors. I like to think of it as keeping you on your feet.

Comment: @RagibZaman Isn't it in the former book as well? I'm actually going off of a PDF that my colleague sent me with a collection of questions from these books (I think).

Comment: @user5965026 The question may be in both books (it's a common question) but I'm fairly sure the incorrect diagram is specific to Zhou's text.